# Kafka SparkStreaming configuration specify offsets/message list size

Tags: configuration, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am fairly new to both Kafka and Spark and trying to write a job (either Streaming or batch). I would like to read from Kafka a predefined number  of messages (say x), process the collection through workers and then only start working on the next set of x messages. Basically each message in Kafka is 10 KB and I want to put 2 GB worth of messages in a single S3 file.
So is there any way of specifying the number of messages that the receiver fetches?
I have read that I can specify 'from offset' while creating DStream, but this use case is somewhat different. I need to be able to specify both 'from offset' and 'to offset'.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to set ending offset as the initial parameter (as you can for starting offset), but
you can use [`createDirectStream`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$) (the fourth overloaded version in the listing) which gives you the ability to get the offsets of the current micro batch using [`HasOffsetRanges`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges) (which gives you back [`OffsetRange`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange)).
That means that you'll have to compare values that you get from `OffsetRange` with your ending offset in every micro batch in order to see where you are and when to stop consuming from Kafka.

I guess you also need to think about the fact that each partition has its sequential offset. I assume it would be easiest if you could go a bit over 2GB, as much as it takes to finish the current micro-batch (could be couple of kB, depending on density of your messages), in order to avoid splitting the last batch on consumed and unconsumed part, which may require you to fiddle with offsets that Spark keeps in order to track what's consumed and what isn't.
Hope this helps.